# Error Running Sonar connected to SQL Server 2005. SONAR.dbo.rules for column description

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sonarqube

When I start Sonar (StartSonar.bat), I get the following error in the log file.

> Wrong column type in SONAR.dbo.rules for column description.
>   Found: ntext, expected: nvarchar(max)

Looking at the column in SQL Server Management Studio it is `nvarchar(max)`

I'm running:

- DB: SQL Server 2005
- OS: Windows 7 64 bit
- Sonar: 2.11

Tried these drivers:

- sqljdbc-1.2.2828.100.jar
- sqljdbc4.jar (Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0)
- sqljdbc4.jar (Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0)
- sqljdbc4.jar (Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 4.0)

My MSSQL Properties:

- sonar.jdbc.url:                        jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SONAR;
- sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
- sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:            select 1
- sonar.jdbc.dialect:                    mssql

I'm using a user name and password (SQL Authentication) to connect the DB

Note to self: When trying to connect to MSSQL remember to Enable TCP/IP. This is found in the SQL Sever Configuration Manager;SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration;Protocols for MSSQLSERVER;TCP/IP

I thought it might be a driver issue, but I'm not sure

Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this via the sqljdbc drivers so I took some advise from another post and fell back to the jTDS driver http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html

The post I used was [Sonar MsSql Database Issue](http://markmail.org/message/fr7ir2nkp5ojtvle#query%3a+page:1+mid%3avvtxhp3xk3kypv4l+state%3aresults)

My Setup:

- Sonar 2.11 unzipped to C:\Sonar\sonar-2.11

The steps I made (paraphrased)

1. Download jTDS drivers from [jTDS Drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/) Unzip it somewhere, I suggest C:\jDST
2. Add the DLL to the system path. (C:\jDST\jtds-1.2.5-dist\x64\SSO)
3. Copy the jar file (C:\jDST\jtds-1.2.5-dist\jtds-1.2.5.jar) to the extensions folder
   (C:\Sonar\sonar-2.11\extensions\jdbc-driver\mssql)
4. Update the sonar.properties

   - sonar.jdbc.url:                          jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/SONAR
   - sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
   - sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
   - sonar.jdbc.dialect: mssql

**Note**: in case you connect to the named instance, this must be specified explicitly in the connection URL: `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/SONAR;instance=SQLEXPRESS`

Run the bat file StartSonar.bat (C:\Sonar\sonar-2.11\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat)

Check your logs and go to  the site http:// localhost:9000

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot! Although, I didn't have to add a DLL to the system path...

Comment: @Jiminy: JDBC connection is not working with Integrated security , Do I need to make any other changes ? it always pass sonar default user name and password while doing connection.