# Sonar and Maven with SQL server on windows

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube

When running Sonar 3.2 I get the following error message displayed when I try to list the projects analyzed in a web browzer.

An error occurred while trying to display the widget "Filter". Please contact the administrator.

when looking at sonars logs I see this message:

> rails  Can not render widget filter: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to execute filter: Filter[rootSnapshotId=,baseSnapshotId=,baseSnapshotPath=,scopes=,qualifiers=[TRK],languages=,favouriteIds=,dateCriterion=,keyRegexp=,nameRegexp=,onDirectChildren=false,measureCriteria=[],periodIndex=0,sortedMetricId=,sortedByMeasureVariation=false,sortedByLanguage=false,sortedByName=true,sortedByKey=false,sortedByDate=false,sortedByVersion=false,isNumericMetric=true,ascendingSort=true], sql=SELECT s.id, MAX(s.project_id) as pid, MAX(s.root_project_id) as rpid, MAX(p.long_name) as name  FROM snapshots s  INNER JOIN projects p ON s.project_id=p.id  WHERE  s.status=:status AND s.islast=:islast  AND s.qualifier IN (:qualifiers)  AND p.copy_resource_id IS NULL  GROUP BY s.id

I am using SQL Server 2008 in the backend. The query doesn't look right for SQL. What could be wrong? When analyzing the project using Maven, I get no issues. It gives me a build success.

I am using Apache Maven 3.0.2 and Sonar 3.2 on window. any clues about what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the sqljdbc drivers to connect to SQL Server?  I solved this issue by using the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128690/1046641).